# How to subset from a list in R

Tags: r, list, sapply

I have a rather simple task but haven't find a good solution.

```
> mylist  
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

[[3]]
[1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32

y <- c(3,5,9)
```

I would like to extract from *mylist* the sub-elements 3,5, and 9 of each component in the list.
I have tried, `sapply[mylist,"[[",y]` but not luck!, and others like vapply, lapply, etc..

Answer (score 40):

You could use `sapply(mylist, "[", y)`:

```
mylist <- list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15)
sapply(mylist, "[", c(2,3))
```

Answer (score 28):

Try using `[` instead of `[[` (and depending on what you're after you light actually want `lapply`).

From `?'[['`:

> The most important distinction between [, [[ and $ is that the [ can
>   select more than one element whereas the other two select a single
>   element.

Answer (score 12):

Using `lapply`:

```
# create mylist
list1<-1:10
list2<-letters[1:26]
list3<-25:32
mylist<-list(list1,list2,list3)

# select 3,5,9th element from each list
list.2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {x[c(3,5,9)]})
```

Answer (score 5):

[purrr](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) provides another solution for solving these kinds of list manipulations within the tidyverse

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

desired_values <- c(1,3)

mylist <- list(1:5, letters[1:6], 11:15) %>% 
purrr::map(`[`,desired_values) 

mylist
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to **subset repeated named elements of a list**, similar to other answers here.

(*so I can find it next time I look this question up*)

E.g., subset the `"b"` elements from a repeating list where each element includes an `"a"` and `"b"` sub-element:

```r
mylist <- list(
  list(
    "a" = runif(3),
    "b" = runif(1)
  ),
  list(
    "a" = runif(3),
    "b" = runif(1)
  )
)

mylist
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] 0.7547490 0.6528348 0.2339767
#> 
#> [[1]]$b
#> [1] 0.8815888
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$a
#> [1] 0.51352909 0.09637425 0.99291650
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] 0.8407162

blist <- lapply(
  X = mylist,
  FUN = function(x){x[["b"]]}
)

blist
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.8815888
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.8407162
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sgibb's answer gives what you would want. I suggest making a new function:

```
subsetList <- function(myList, elementNames) {
    lapply(elementNames, FUN=function(x) myList[[x]])
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
x <- list(a=3, b="hello", c=4.5, d="world")
subsetList(x, c("d", "a"))
subsetList(x, c(4, 1))
```

These both give

```
[[1]]
[1] "world"

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

which is what you would want, I think.

Comment: I have used this solution, but for some reason, it adds a column containing the index to each element. very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, but here's a quick solution.

```
# your values
list1<-1:10
list2<-letters[1:26]
list3<-25:32

# put 'em together in a list
mylist<-list(list1,list2,list3)

# function
foo<-function(x){x[c(3,5,9)]}

# apply function to each of the element in the list
foo(mylist[[1]])
foo(mylist[[2]])
foo(mylist[[3]])

# check the output

> foo(mylist[[1]])
[1] 3 5 9
> foo(mylist[[2]])
[1] "c" "e" "i"
> foo(mylist[[3]])
[1] 27 29 NA
```

Comment: Please use `lapply`, right now this solution does not scale at all when `mylist` becomes bigger.