# What documentation tells us that "[" can be used as a function?

Tags: r, list, subset, sapply

Several of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9624169/10319707) suggest that the best way to extract a subset from a list is to use something like `sapply(mylist, "[", y)`. I found this rather disturbing, because I have never seen anything to suggest that we can use "[" as if it's a function. Where is this documented? I checked `?'[['` for my version, 3.6.3, but I can't see any reference to this functionality in [that documentation](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Comment: All operators in R are functions. This is documented in the language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators

Comment: @Roland ```'+'(3,4)``` works? Great. I didn't expect to be able to make my R code look like Lisp.

Comment: R's design was inspired by Scheme.

Comment: @J.Mini `'+'(3,4)` does not work. You have to use backticks.

Comment: @bcarlsen You are mistaken. Try it.

Comment: I am wrong! but from reading `?Quotes` this seems kind of horrible. `[...] under many circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to a name)` is not the kind of reassuring stability you want in a language spec

Comment: @bcarlsen Out of context, this quote sounds worse than it is. It's all very stable. The wording is used because there are exceptions where you can't use single or double quotes. The next sentence points to such an exception. It similar to the difference between `<-` and `=`. Mostly, they are interchangeable, except within expressions that are function calls.

Comment: I highly recommend getting a (free) copy of "The R-Inferno" .   https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All operators in R are functions. This is documented in the language definition:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators

> Like the other operators, indexing is really done by functions, and one could have used `` `[`(x, 2) `` instead of `x[2]`.

Comment: And for real fun,  look at the source code for the package `sos` , function --- well, operator `???`